# Is it possible to define different Examples for same type T Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters.IExamplesProvider<T> and get both of them working?

Tags: swagger-ui, dry

When I try using different example methods for same class i.e typeof(ErrorResponse), in Swagger UI, both MyMethod1 and MyMethod2 gets only the example defined in ErrorResponseExampleMethod2.

Is there a way to define method specific examples but still not define method specific types?
Please note that 'ErrorResponse' is used as a example use case and it may not be the best and it is used to provide clarity to the question.

I already know defining method specific types 'ErrorResponseMyMethod1' and 'ErrorResponseMyMethod2' is a solution but the question is about defining examples without cluttering schemas section of Swagger UI.

```cs
[HttpGet("method1")]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Bad Request", typeof(ErrorResponse))]
public IActionResult MyMethod1()
{
    // ...
}

[HttpGet("method2")]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Bad Request", typeof(ErrorResponse))]
public IActionResult MyMethod2()
{
    // ...
}

public class ErrorResponseExampleMethod1 : IExamplesProvider<ErrorResponse>
{
    public ErrorResponse GetExamples()
    {
        return new ErrorResponse
        {
            StatusCode = 400,
            Message = "Bad Request - Method 1",
            Errors = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Field1", "Error message 1" },
                { "Field2", "Error message 2" }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class ErrorResponseExampleMethod2 : IExamplesProvider<ErrorResponse>
{
    public ErrorResponse GetExamples()
    {
        return new ErrorResponse
        {
            StatusCode = 400,
            Message = "Bad Request - Method 2",
            Errors = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Field1", "Error message 3" },
                { "Field2", "Error message 4" }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class ErrorResponse
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Errors { get; set; }
    }
```

what I have tried is explained in details above